# Lebesgue integral by simple and bounded functions

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $f: E \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ is measurable. Prove the following:
$\sup \{\int \psi \ | \ 0 \leq \psi \leq f, \ \psi \ \text{is a simple function}\}=\sup \{\int_F h \ | \ 0 \leq h \leq f, \ h \ \text{measurable and bounded}, \ F \subset E, \ m(F)<\infty \}$.

I don't have an idea o prove this preposition that is in a measure theory book and I want to know the result soon. Will really appreciate any help...

Comment: The best way to show this is to show that the LHS is less than or equal to the RHS, and then to show that the RHS is less than or equal to the LHS. The first of these is easier, since a simple function is measurable and bounded.

Comment: Do you have an idea about the second part?

Answer (score 1):

I would follow Michael Lee's instruction. To see the second part you can argue like this:

Assum $0 \leq h \leq f$ is measurable and bounded, and $F \subset E, m(F)< \infty$. We need to show that there exists a simple function $\psi$ with $ 0 \leq \psi \leq f$ and $\int \psi \, dm \geq \int_F h \, dm$. First observe, that you can construct a monotone sequence of simple functions $f_n$ with $f_n \to 1_F \cdot h $ and $ 1_F \cdot h \leq f_n \leq f $. Thus we get from the monotonic convergence theorem

$$ \lim \int f_n \, dm = \int_F h \, dm $$

Now from $m(F)< \infty$ and the fact that $h$ is bounded, we have $\int_F h \, dm < \infty$. Thus there exists an $n$ with $$\int f_n \, dm \geq \int_F h \, dm $$